# É possível alterar um texto de um "content" de um pseudo-elemento do CSS através do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Exemplo abaixo

```
#test{
    content:"blablabla";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regras `:before` e `:after` não fazem parte do **DOM** e, portanto, não podem ser alteradas usando os métodos *DOM* do *jQuery*.

Mas existem maneiras de manipular esses elementos usando soluções de *JavaScript* e ou *CSS*. Uma das maneiras usando *jQuery* é como o @PauloImon respondeu, você pode fazer com *JavaScript* puro, veja:

```js
let paragrafo = document.querySelector('#paragrafo');
paragrafo.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  paragrafo.setAttribute('data-conteudo', 'Novo texto');
});
```

```css
p:before {
    content: attr(data-conteudo);
}
```

```html
<p id="paragrafo" data-conteudo="Paragrafo"></p>
```

Pode também, adicionar ou remover classes, veja:

```js
let paragrafo = document.querySelector('#paragrafo');
paragrafo.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  paragrafo.classList.toggle('novotexto');
});
```

```css
p:before {
    content: "Paragrafo";
}
p.novotexto:before {
    content: "Novo texto";
}
```

```html
<p id="paragrafo"></p>
```

Você pode ver mais exemplo nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/8353154) no *SOen*.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer, mas é uma saída usando *jQuery*:

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  $('div').attr('data-conteudo', 'Mudou!');
});
```

```css
div::before
{
  content: attr(data-conteudo); /* Recebe o conteúdo do atributo data-conteudo */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-conteudo="Teste"></div>
<br>
<button type="button">Alterar</button>
```